# Bash batch file rename

Tags: bash, rename

This is probably an easy question for Bash experts, but can you please help me correct my script.

I want to take every .png file in a directory and rename and save it in another folder. I want to take the first file and rename it "SV314r.png", the next file should be "SV314v.png", the next file should be "SV315r.png" and the next "SV315v.png" and so on.

It needs to alternate from r to v, to indicate "front (recto)" and "back (verso)" for each folio page number. I'm getting errors with my "if" conditional and with my attempt to increase the "num" variable and switch the "side" variable from r to v.

```
num=314
side="r"
for file in *.png
do 

    cp "${file}" "../rename/SV"$num$side".png"

    if [ $side == "r" ]; then
        num=$num
        side="v"
    else
        num=$num + 1
        side="r"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue here is with **arithmetic evaluation** in `bash`.

Replace

```
  num=$num + 1
```

by

```
  num=$(( $num + 1 ))
```

Besides **variable expansion** occurs inside double quotes. Therefore the extra quotes are not necessary.

```
  cp "${file}" "../rename/SV${num}${side}.png"
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors: ./filerename.sh: line 10: [: missing `]'
./filerename.sh: line 14: num: command not found
./filerename.sh: line 15: side: command not found

Comment: @Jeff check if there is a space between `num` and `=` sign. There should not be.